# AFNetworking reachabilityForLocalWiFi

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, afnetworking-2

Is there a way with AFNetworking 2 to have the equivalence of

```
[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into Apple reachability code and I think this will do the job.

```
- (AFNetworkReachabilityManager*) reachabilityForLocalWifi
{
    struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;
    bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
    localWifiAddress.sin_len = sizeof(localWifiAddress);
    localWifiAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0.
    localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM);

    return [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForAddress:&localWifiAddress];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = manager.operationQueue;
[manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
switch (status) {
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
        [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
        break;
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
    default:
        [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
        break;
}
}];
```

i am using this in my custom client in some of project , for checking  internet reachability. 
 reference [afnetworking link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I am looking for. I want to check for local wifi reachability not internet reachability. Thanks for your help.